# Why does UpdateData() not work in EN_CHANGE handler for MFC CEdit control

Tags: c++, mfc

It seems like the simplest thing (using Visual Studio):

- Place an edit control (MFC `CEdit`) on a dialog
- Right click and choose "Add variable..."
- Link the control to a variable (e.g. CString someText)
- Right click on the control again and choose "Add Event Handler..."
- Click the "Add and Edit" button so it adds an `EN_CHANGE` event handler
- The class wizard generates a handler function like `OnEnChangeEdtSomeText()`

Terrific - each time a character is typed, the handler function is invoked. However, on all other events I have ever handled with MFC controls, `UpdateData()` would exchange data between the control and a variable linked to it - the state of the control is reflected in the state of the linked variable after `UpdateData()` is called. Why not here? Clearly I have to use something else, and so far `GetWindowText()` seems to work fine for retrieving the text I can see in the `CEdit` control.

But why has the normal function of `UpdateData()` been destroyed? For example, if I type "foo" into my edit control, then click or tab away to kill focus, then return to type "bar", on none of the invocations of `OnEnChangeEdtSomeText()` (all 6 of them) does `UpdateData()` lead to any data whatsoever in the variable linked to it. Why not? Can I trust `EN_CHANGE` not to interfere with other data entry? Are there other notifications that will break what I had come to believe was the normal link between a control and a variable linked through a `DDX...` mechanism?

Comment: *"But how does one actually get the character just typed?"* - That's a wrong assumption. `EN_CHANGE` can be raised, when the user didn't type a character (e.g. pasting from the clipboard with the mouse). It's not clear, what problem you are really trying to solve. This question is asking about your proposed solution only.

Comment: You are right - that was a rhetorical question that I have edited out. Hopefully the question is clearer now.

Comment: You can trace into `UpdateData` to see exactly what it's doing and why it's failing. But calling `UpdateData` on every character input is an abuse of the system - even if you get it working, I would recommend using `GetWindowText` as you're currently doing.

Comment: Clearly `UpdateData()` is not the right thing to use in this particular context - that's fine. But I'm really surprised that it seems to break completely as if `EN_CHANGE` is some kind of kryptonite to it. Since `UpdateData()` is used so liberally in the software I'm using, I'd like to understand what hidden traps there might be with it.

Comment: @omatai I just tried exactly what you have described, and it works just fine here. Without seeing your actual source code (or at least the relevant parts suche as the .h file and the `DoDataExchange` function) it's somewhat hard to help.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - thanks. I have more pressing priorities right now than to dig into it, but it sounds like it is probably supposed to work, but something breaks it. I can only ever recall trying to use `EN_CHANGE` once or twice before, and always hitting this problem. I agree with Mark Ransom that `UpdateData()` is probably not the right thing to be using anyway, and that the answer lies in tracing into it. When my deadlines ease, I'll follow that path.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a rich edit, you need to call `SetEventMask(ENM_CHANGE)` on it, or the message will not be sent on edition.