# User Subclassed class from CEdit value validation if DDX_Text is use

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dialog, cedit

I have my own class (`CMyEdit`) subclassed from `CEdit` with own validation procedure.

I hook events `ON_CHAR` and `ON_UPDATE` and validate user input.

If the input is valid, attribute `CMyEdit::isOk` is switched to `true`. `CMyEdit` confirms validity during each change of EditBox content.

Dialog could confirm validity by `CMyEdit::isOk`.

I have overridden `CEdit::SetWindowText()`

```
inline void CMyEdit::SetWindowText(LPCTSTR lsText)
{
    CEdit::SetWindowText(lsText);
    Validate(); //set isOk true or false
}
```

But if dialog uses `DDX_Text`, no method is running (Nor `EN_CHANGE`, neither `SetWindowText)`.

The same problem is, when user put value from clipboard (`WM_PASTE`).

How to hook this change of EditBox content?

Comment: Have you read this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123991/why-does-updatedata-not-work-in-en-change-handler-for-mfc-cedit-control)? And there is a piece of code in the definition of UpdateData that prevents scheduling control notifications, so the Windows procedure of the edit control's parent window does not receive EN_UPDATE and EN_CHANGE notifications.